# Weka how to split dataset into 70-30 with StratifiedRemoveFolds filter?

Tags: java, weka

I want to split my dataset into 70% train and 30% test using java code. I am trying to use StratifiedRemoveFolds. I was able to use it successfully when my percentages were 75% and 25% (split into 4 folds and select the first which is 25%, then invert and get the other 3/4) or 66% and 33% (split into 3 folds, select the first which is 33% then invert and get the other 2/3) but I can't get it working when the fold I am selecting is not 1. The size of my test dataset ends up being 10% instead of 30%. Here is my code:

```
        StratifiedRemoveFolds filter = new StratifiedRemoveFolds();

        String[] options = new String[6];

        options[0] = "-N"; // number of folds
        options[1] = Integer.toString(10); // split the data into 10 random folds
        options[2] = "-F"; // select a fold
        options[3] = Integer.toString(3); // select the first 3 folds??
        options[4] = "-S"; // set the random seed
        options[5] = Integer.toString(1); // set the random seed to 1

        filter.setOptions(options); 
        filter.setInputFormat(data); 
        filter.setInvertSelection(false); 

        Instances test = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);

        filter.setInvertSelection(true); 
        Instances train = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
```